# Programatically put meta description in Magento cms Pages

Tags: magento-1.9, import, cms, csv

I have more than 500 cms pages in my Magento store, and i want to change all meta descriptions based on a CSV file. There are two columns in my csv file:

1. Cms Page identifier
2. Meta description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy this code and put it on your magento root directory,You need to change your file path.

```
<?php   
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '600M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin'); 

$fileLocation = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'metadata.csv';
$mage_csv = new Varien_File_Csv(); //mage CSV
$data = $mage_csv->getData($fileLocation); //path to csv
$cmsData = Mage::getModel('cms/page');

foreach ($data as $_data) {
    $pageTitle = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($_data[0], 'identifier');
    if ($pageTitle->getPageId()) {
        $pageTitle->setMetaDescription($_data[1]);
        $pageTitle->save();
    }
}

echo 'done meta';
```

Comment: this works, but it will take 1.3 eternities for 500 pages.

Comment: @kanika it's working

Answer (score 2):

The cms pages are flat entities. This means that each cms page is stored as a row in the table `cms_page`.
You can write a simple php script that parses the csv file and just runs queries like this:

```
UPDATE `cms_page` set `meta_description` = 'YOur meta description here' where `identifier` = 'identifier_here';
```